# Select option with ngModel

Tags: javascript, html, angular, angular-ngmodel, angular2-ngmodel

I have a project that has a select of several questions and I would like the first one to appear by default.

I have seen an example of how to achieve this using the index, of the type:

```
<select>
 <option *ngFor="let answer of answers; let i = index" [value]="answer.id" [selected]="i == 2">
  {{answer.name}}
 </option> 
</select>
```

and it works, but when I want to bind the select to a property of the component, it is no longer selected:

```
<select  [(ngModel)]=searchterms.answerId>
 <option *ngFor="let answer of answers; let i = index" [value]="answer.id" [selected]="i == 2">
  {‌{answer.name}}
 </option> 
</select>
```

You can see an example here:

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-rv9vqi

As say in some answers the solution is to set a default value to the serachterm, but the problem I have, (I am not able to reproduce it in the playground) is that I receive those answers from a service that asks to a back, and when the component is built it still does not have them and it gives me an error .... how can I make it assign those searchterms the value once they exist in the service?

Answer (score 5):

You can use Angulars two-way data binding to bind to the [value attribute](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_select_value.asp) of the `<select>` element. In your example it would look like this:

```
<select [(value)]="searchterms.answerId">  
    <option *ngFor="let answer of answers" [value]="answer.id">{{answer.name}}</option>  
</select>
```

Notice how binding to the `value` attribute cleans up the `option` element, by enabling you to remove the `[selected]="i == 2"` and `let i = index`

However, like the others have mentioned you will want to initialize the desired default value in your component code.

Here is the working [StackBlitz Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-apcr2b) with your code

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the `searchterms.answerId` with a proper default value. In your case

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: [ './app.component.css' ]
})
export class AppComponent  {
  name = 'Angular 6';
  answers = [
    {name: "Answer 1", id: '1'},
    {name: "Answer 2", id: '2'},
    {name: "Answer 3", id: '3'},
    {name: "Answer 4", id: '4'},
  ];
  searchterms = {
    answerId: this.answers[1].id //Set the default value properly
  };
}
```

[stackblitz](https://angular-5ixdgq.stackblitz.io)

Answer (score 0):

Then you should bind `searchterms` in your component.

you can do it inside `constructor` as follows.

```
this.searchterms.answerId = this.answers[1].id;
```

**[Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-sppj2v?file=src/app/app.component.ts)**